# scrapy response not able to crawl because of bad characters

Tags: python, scrapy

[image]

In the picture you can see operator has some bad characters in the name.  These fix themselves and show in chrome but on scrapy when I run even response.text in the shell I get

`scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Response content isn't text`

When I check other jobs where the operator doesnt have this text I can run the script fine and grab all the data.

I am sure its due to unicodes.  I and not sure how to tell scrapy to ignore them and run the rest as text so I can **scrape** anything.

below is just a skeleton of my code

```
class PrintSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "printer_data"

    start_urls = [
        'http://192.168.4.107/jobid-15547'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
      job_dict = {}
      url_split = response.request.url.split('/')
      job_dict['job_id'] = url_split[len(url_split)-1].split('-',1)[1]  

      job_dict['job_name'] = response.xpath("/html/body/fieldset/big[1]/text()").extract_first().split(': ', 1)[1] # this breaks here.
```

**Update with other things I have tried already**

I have worked with this for a while in the scrapy shell.  response.text gives the exception I put earlier.  this check is also in the response.xpath.

I have looked at the code a little bit but cannot find how response.text is working.  I feel like I need to fix these characters in the response somehow so that scrapy will see it as text and can process the html instead of ignoring the entire page so I cannot access anything.

I also would love a way to save the response to a file without opening in chrome and saving so that I can work with the original document for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be however not necessary. Try following approach to see what your crawler see:

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

def parse(self, response):
    open_in_browser (response)
```

This will open the page in browser - make sure you are not doing this in a loop otherwise your browser will get stuck.

Secondly, try to fetch HTML first and see if this works fine.

```
response.xpath("/html/body/fieldset/big[1]/text()").extract_first()
```

modify to:

```
response.xpath("/html/body/fieldset/big[1]")[0].extract()
```

If second approach fixes the issue, then go with bs4 or lxml to convert html to text.

Furthermore, if this is a public link, let us know the link along with complete log for further understanding of the issue.

Comment: I would love to have a link but this printer is directly connected to a computer and only way to access it is at that spot.  As for the response.xpath.  I cannot use it because response says it is not text.  even response.text gives the same error.  It is because those 2 bytes which chrome automatically fixes when visiting the page, scrapy sees as not an actual html document.  I need a way to ignore those bits like chrome does so then scrapy will see it as text.